# Can Azure B2C claims exchange be used for Access token?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I got the workaround to work to add claims to the token using a custom REST API, however I realized this is the Id token and not the Access token.  I need the custom claims to be the Access token to use for authorization in the service.

I haven't inspected the Access token yet but are these claims also inserted into the Access token?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, custom claims come back when requesting access tokens.  The only difference in the list of claims is the `scp` claim.  The `scp` claim is only returned on [access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens#access-tokens).

Unfortunately, the [Claims in ID and access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens#claims-in-id-and-access-tokens) documentation doesn't discuss this.

---

You can quickly verify this via the Run Now feature in the Azure Portal.  [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49307987/185123).

[Sample access token w/ a custom claim](https://jwt.ms/#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vODAwMzNkZmQtNmVhYi00MmM0LWJkZjItNGUyMjNkNGIzOTZmL3YyLjAvIiwiZXhwIjoxNTIxMTQzNTA3LCJuYmYiOjE1MjExMzk5MDcsImF1ZCI6IjQ5Nzg5MDU2LTA5YzEtNGFkMS04MDM4LWIwMjM1NDcyZjM2ZSIsInN1YiI6IjU0ZDg0YWMwLTdjOWUtNDFlNC05MWQ3LTM0OTZjYzgyOGI0OSIsImV4dGVuc2lvbl9NeUN1c3RvbUNsYWltIjoiSGVsbG8gV29ybGQiLCJ0ZnAiOiJCMkNfMV9TTy1NaWtlRG91Z2xhc0RldiIsIm5vbmNlIjoiZGVmYXVsdE5vbmNlIiwic2NwIjoiZGVtby5yZWFkIGRlbW8ud3JpdGUgdXNlcl9pbXBlcnNvbmF0aW9uIFRlc3QtVmFsdWUiLCJhenAiOiJkMzliZjhiZi1kYzBhLTQ3YzYtOGM1NS1mYjBhYWRhNTNkMjMiLCJ2ZXIiOiIxLjAiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjExMzk5MDd9.AF6XW09lM7pTAymIBPEWZY9d6PyiBrGk-0UYo1K3bqS8zJKU9CnNLIi6RNrLmKjOWdGixNIE5XcDh7NB5QtakreSGwehYnEY0ejrbhIPTeBdsh-X6j97ylKHV3Q0WmA25gZkzpBzSQpvWhL51rWJXGmQJtuPmAgEEzIDU1fqpFrYsfiQK83z-mE9TdgW1H54arCRVmXXz9Gysin0iErhLoqYk9U80SThfhtukkkTA0mOl4_keZfTkubCQnqtaijwPWla8T7T2WXNiPTA6brV-6qvHdinYQM9bD-30NWKHZZdlf4w608lKzDu6mlw9b3xQGzDHxQwKXjKBLGWaymXjw&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsifQ.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.lzdkymYrgKffix3H155dYIt-XKhMqyKu5elGy_R7-11hKNpv9piINTu5h6yk0w22nx1uaFAjHGhRCDbnpGX45_-gMrDt0UWu2KF2TTZn5E9HXbcBA1qix4opODlO365quJEaL8AghBWxOisLhFThrwwQ9s1cAzFbq2pQ6icq29FIHPYP9I5eXnOJQw21813CE2Ry1hpUsk7uswhfzS7FlZrGN3nL9cFO0hjMMIgVXXJiLCZXb0g18XQT5uA3jQmbka8frFvpY8vWHWiuccvWKJpQUTDiulKjOJPC48zSvptiZ6xGOJDSMnDmJYLJay8N2DJboS6uZgMJEGr_s5RHLw)

[image: sample access token w/ a custom claim]

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks for highlighting the results.

Answer (score 2):

I am using custom claims in my Azure Active Directory B2C tenant where I registered two applications (UI and API). The UI passes the access_token to the API and I am **able to retrieve the custom claims** there. I guess this should be also true for custom claims using a custom REST API.

If not, It must be possible to setup:

> ... The return claims can be stored in the user's Azure AD account,
>   evaluated in the next Orchestration Steps, or included in the access
>   token

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll verify in our POC app today.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "Can I get the user's access token from the federating IdP such as Azure AD, facebook etc"?  The answer currently is no. You can vote for this feature here.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334347-return-social-idp-s-native-access-tokens-back-to-t

Comment: Hi Montel, I can see how this would be important for IdPs that also offer Graph like APIs but this isn't our need.  I basically want to make sure that we can customize the policies to add custom claims/attributes to the access token in addition to the identity token.