# How do I view the claims returned from B2C? | B2C JWT Viewer

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How can I easily view the id token and access tokens returned from B2C?  I know there are tools like https://jwt.io/ but I have manually copy and paste tokens from the URL.  Surely, there has to be an easier way, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Setup**

1. [Create a B2C Web App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp#optional-step-5-create-your-own-web-app) called Token Viewer

   - set the reply url to https://jwt.ms
     [image: token viewer app prop screenshot]
2. Give it access any published scopes
   [image: api access screenshot]

**Execute a Policy**

1. Open one of your policies
2. Change the app Token View
3. Clicking run now will get you an **id token**
   [image: run now screenshot for id tokens]
   [Sample ID Token](https://jwt.ms/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsifQ.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.Tcno9iJzF3RyXWjHsQFdPcgYe5Bb8zK3-uSQahleQtInxbogq3A5wRs-LcLf9rW8UQ2SAtgzPbotUSCApCXRYLRDXMavbAe5iut4wAMvjmAMNcU2apspjPwee0TwOnoXXVMwUXgYHV7G_csQ7K9VtofgGdwlyvUhoEDxNkSy1rvDPJ66d2KXu8x7ATtYBTGkLYMqIGVwRC7YQiF4f-l90e3xydSVQINdHHFbnji9XK8ZWUBw6JYDZqF7qRR9G-Rwe60DAb79airiiwnFKr9uUITL5Z9aByYe1j5hwQefYNJ0L8CqfNCEH0xQ8LXijo3IfwaAxkaWwatG7xud08OsIA)
4. Expand ACCESS TOKENS to obtain an **access token**
   [image: run now screenshot for access tokens]

**Review the Results**

The following is a sample access token on https://jwt.ms

[image: sample access token screenshot]

[Sample access token](https://jwt.ms/#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsifQ.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.hYm73v7xtcZYoZ-VWfeANAqE3oJh_ytGalwkuA0-6xYjiAG47fRK4AH6RmtY6Z0mtBKpTVNQNUD8Swb_O_kv8FGFm1C8y6sV71tfMfcFplyzTpY35HfKHx7D9N7bwDE4ZZgqaslhJfegCOZtcnqlu9Huep_--MP_TkAck1HazJokI0MrXOUi6nNaWNk1Tu-cvlHD8MFPnl9EJbvloA0_7r1dnO4yD6hiSMGIDseR4tC2AOGM9MQVBV1yBVpaUQf960_biBwfuo2CTeq3iFcog0xgg6jIsSHroGTx7j8T_weaF6cI6doUNGOlwxXAvTzHweB11lL81I4OudmWd4TOgA&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsifQ.eyJleHAiOjE1MjExNDYzNDgsIm5iZiI6MTUyMTE0Mjc0OCwidmVyIjoiMS4wIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2dpbi5taWNyb3NvZnRvbmxpbmUuY29tLzgwMDMzZGZkLTZlYWItNDJjNC1iZGYyLTRlMjIzZDRiMzk2Zi92Mi4wLyIsInN1YiI6IjU0ZDg0YWMwLTdjOWUtNDFlNC05MWQ3LTM0OTZjYzgyOGI0OSIsImF1ZCI6ImQzOWJmOGJmLWRjMGEtNDdjNi04YzU1LWZiMGFhZGE1M2QyMyIsIm5vbmNlIjoiZGVmYXVsdE5vbmNlIiwiaWF0IjoxNTIxMTQyNzQ4LCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1MjExNDI3NDgsInRmcCI6IkIyQ18xX1Rva2VuVmlld2VyIiwiYXRfaGFzaCI6InZqVlE2Q1M3cU1WVlBDYzRRa0R2RHcifQ.Y6bQ1rvoCxtjw7U6zuCY-VQgFee8sbSFMBG1ZLTpbBiY5gocyF1SAxdodWguD6AdyhR4Fz80a3ezclG2u7he2iGqggsZfei_LS5YwRrVnJxzWUXClgCXuVSrCjFT4cuiS6p7WLXQtEndKxKPp8dSl956Y3InHly1ZDBOOcSHURUotZIdw_K4NSytmFFngf8t3opDKleliUQKBlbKvtn8KBZfLcnWTjnJSqcTIdmxeQtlYIty4F0DFpaw3S2rPjq55RHVnWGyQMU-MHdLegU2HJ2aUfUT7a4agqolmOUTtUPz9o25-aQguMd5nexmZnRGIw39zq7uJrekCjNe6AqgeQ)