# Scope claim is null when requesting web api from Angular 4 SPA

Tags: c#, angular, azure-ad-b2c, claims, msal.js

I am trying to protect my web api using Azure B2C AD and consume the web api using an Angular 4 SPA. However, for some reason the scope claim is always null even though other claims are working just fine.

I am using the MSAL library version 0.1.6 in the Angular app and have been following this guide: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular2.4-spa

This is my web api startup.auth:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // These values are pulled from web.config
    public static string AadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AadInstance"];
    public static string Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    public static string ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    public static string SignUpSignInPolicy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId"];
    public static string DefaultPolicy = SignUpSignInPolicy;

    /*
     * Configure the authorization OWIN middleware.
     */
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // Accept only those tokens where the audience of the token is equal to the client ID of this app
            ValidAudience = ClientId,
            AuthenticationType = Startup.DefaultPolicy
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // This SecurityTokenProvider fetches the Azure AD B2C metadata & signing keys from the OpenIDConnect metadata endpoint
            AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy))),

        });
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
[Authorize]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] // tune to your needs
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        string owner = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        var scopes = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope");
        return new string[] {"value1", "value2"};
    }
}
```

The owner variable contains a GUID as expected, however the scopes variable is always NULL.

This is my auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import environment from '../../../environments/environment';
import * as Msal from 'msal'

declare var bootbox: any;
// declare var Msal:any;

const B2CTodoAccessTokenKey = "b2c.api.access.token";

const tenantConfig = {
        tenant: environment.b2cTenant,
        clientID: environment.b2cClientID,
        signUpSignInPolicy: environment.b2cSignUpSignInPolicy,
        b2cScopes: environment.b2cScopes
    };

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    // Configure the authority for Azure AD B2C
    private authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/" + tenantConfig.tenant + "/" + tenantConfig.signUpSignInPolicy;

    private loggerCallback(logLevel, message, piiLoggingEnabled) {
        console.log(message);
    }    

    private logger = new Msal.Logger(this.loggerCallback, { level: Msal.LogLevel.Verbose }); 

    clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
        tenantConfig.clientID, 
        this.authority, 
        function(errorDesc: any, token: any, error: any, tokenType: any) {
            console.log('calling acquireTokenSilent with scopes: ' + tenantConfig.b2cScopes);
            console.log('idtoken: ' + token)
            if (token) {
                this.acquireTokenSilent(tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
                    // Change button to Sign Out
                    console.log('acquireTokenSilent');
                    sessionStorage.setItem("b2c.api.access.token", accessToken);
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.acquireTokenPopup(tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
                        console.log('acquireTokenPopup');
                        sessionStorage.setItem("b2c.api.access.token", accessToken);
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                });
            }
            else if (errorDesc || error) {
                console.log(error + ':' + errorDesc);
            }
        },
        { 
            logger: this.logger,
        });

    loginRedirect(): void {
        console.log('scopes: ' + tenantConfig.b2cScopes);
        this.clientApplication.loginRedirect(tenantConfig.b2cScopes);
    }

    login() : void {
        var _this = this;
        this.clientApplication.loginPopup(tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (idToken: any) {
            _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
                function (accessToken: any) {
                    _this.saveAccessTokenToCache(accessToken);
                }, function (error: any) {
                    _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
                        function (accessToken: any) {
                            _this.saveAccessTokenToCache(accessToken);
                        }, function (error: any) {
                            //bootbox.alert("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error);
                            console.log("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error)
                        });
                })
        }, function (error: any) {
            //bootbox.alert("Error during login:\n" + error);
            console.log("Error during login:\n" + error);
        });
    }

    getTokenFromCache() : string {
        return sessionStorage.getItem(B2CTodoAccessTokenKey);
    }

    saveAccessTokenToCache(accessToken: string): void {
        sessionStorage.setItem(B2CTodoAccessTokenKey, accessToken);
    }

    logout(): void{
        this.clientApplication.logout();
    }

    isLoggedIn(): boolean {        
        var user = this.clientApplication.getUser();

        console.log('isLogged In: ' + (user != null));        
        console.log('token in cache ' + (this.getTokenFromCache() != null))
        //console.log('token: ' + this.getTokenFromCache());
        return this.clientApplication.getUser() != null && this.getTokenFromCache() != null; 

    }
}
```

Finally, this is my environment values:

```
export default {
    b2cTenant: "[tenant].onmicrosoft.com",
    b2cClientID: '[app-id]',
    b2cSignUpSignInPolicy: "[policy]",
    b2cScopes: ["https://[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/apidemo/read", "https://[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/apidemo/user_impersonation"]
};
```

Here is pictures of the Azure setup:

API properties:
[image: API properties]

API published scopes:
[image: API published scopes]

Client API access:
[image: Client API access]

Why is the value of the scopes variable NULL? What did I miss?
The owner variable contains a value!

Best regards

Comment: In the Azure AD B2C portal, did you grant access by your web app to your web API, using the **API Access** blade (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#create-a-web-app-client-secret)?

Comment: I am not sure I did it correctly - I will update the psot with screenshots of the current setup

Comment: I would start with the portal first, eliminate ur app code from the pic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49307987/185123

Comment: Can you get an access token from the portal with the scope claim filled out?  If no, then B2C config appears to be wrong.  If yes, your app code appears to be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did as you suggested and now I can get an access token but there is no scope claim filled out when I call the API. Then my B2C config in the portal is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try running fiddler to see what is going on.

1. You may need to define Users and Roles to accomplish this. See [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#AppRoleType).
2. One of your config settings may not match what you have in your app registration. Ensure that the ClientID/AppID matches in all instances.
3. Make sure that the reply urls in your code match what you have in the app registration.

Please see if [this issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/issues/24) is relevant to you.

Comment: Thanks.

The issue is not that the access token is null, but that the scope claim is null. 

Regarding option 2 + 3 I confirmed that they match in all instances (.NET app, SPA, Azure portal).

Regarding option 1, I am unsure which section you refer to since none of them seem really relevant here - or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using a different client library: https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client

In case anyone posts a solution, using the MSAL library, I will ofcourse mark it as the solution