# How to get custom Azure Active Directory B2C user attributes using .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Using Azure B2C Active Directory. Enforcing authentication. I'm able to get the user and email address. However I do I get a custom attribute with c#?

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("authenticated/profile")]
        public string GetCustomAttribute()
        {
            var user = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var customAttribute = ?
    }
```

Sifted through documentation and reviewed similar posts on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using user flows to login to Azure AD B2C, then you may need to create the extension attribute from the portal itself.

Please refer [to microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow#create-a-custom-attribute) to create custom attributes. After creating, ensure you have selected the new custom attribute in the user flow settings to return it in the token.
Read the claim from token to get it.

If you are using custom policies with Azure AD B2C, you could create the custom attribute using graph. Make sure you read the custom attribute and output the claim in your RP file.
[Microsoft docs for custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#create-a-custom-attribute)

Comment: I'm looking to find how to retrieve the attribute, not set it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the attribute is included in the token? Instructions on viewing the token can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307986/how-do-i-view-the-claims-returned-from-b2c-b2c-jwt-viewer).

If it is not included in the token, instructions to include it can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

Make sure you refer to the claim by the right name, there might be an "extension_" before the name

Comment: Nice. Do you happen to know if there is a way to edit the label that appears in the UI? For the life of me I have been unable to find it in the portal.

Comment: If you are using user flow, then that would be handled under localization. Details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-user-flow#change-extension-attributes)